# How do I create a new worksheet and populate it with rows of data using Excel-DNA?

Tags: c#, excel-dna

I have c# code behind my Excel-dna addin which is successfully downloading data from a service. I have created a ribbon in Excel-dna with a button which triggers the download, and now I want to display the data in a new worksheet. How do I create a worksheet and add rows?

I tried calling [xlcWorkbookInsert](https://groups.google.com/group/exceldna/browse_frm/thread/cc87114539c78f53) from my c# code using:

```
  ExcelReference newSheet = (ExcelReference)XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcWorkbookInsert, 1);
```

but I always get a ExcelDna.Integration.XlCallException exception. Is this the correct approach, or is there a simpler way to go about doing this?

I also tried pasting an `object[,]` of data to an existing sheet:

```
   ExcelReference sheet1 = (ExcelReference)XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlSheetId, "Sheet1");

   ExcelReference myTargetPasteArea = new ExcelReference(1, 1, 2, 10, sheet1.SheetId);

   myTargetPasteArea.SetValue(result);
```

There are no errors this time, but nothing happens (although I can see the code being executed when I step through in debug).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is calling to Excel via the C API (that's how the XlCall.Excel(...) and ExcelReference stuff in [Excel-DNA](http://exceldna.codeplex.com) works). But you can't call the C API directly from your ribbon event handler. You have two options:

- Make a detour via a macro. This is easy if you change your ribbon xml code:

  <button onAction="RunTagMacro" tag="MyMacro" />

and then define a macro:

```
public static void MyMacro()
{
    // ... do your work here ....
}
```

You can also call the macro yourself from the event handler - the `RunTagMacro` internally just calls

```
object app = ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
app.GetType().InvokeMember("Run", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, 
    null, app, new object[] { control.Tag }, new CultureInfo(1033));
```

- Another option is to change your interaction code to use the COM API. For this you'll need to use the 'dynamic' support in .NET 4, or reference an interop assembly - either the version-specific Primary Interop Assemblies for Office, or some version-independent interop assemblies like [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I think the ribbon xml code you posted got eaten though. Can you repost it?

Comment: Ah, I tried the code based approach and now I can create a new sheet and write to it with the code I had before. (I can't get the RunTagMacro attribute to work though, but no matter). Thanks! <333

Comment: Can the macro method have parameters?

Comment: Thanks - I fixed the xml. Your macro can have parameters if you call it yourself - also add the params to the InvokeMember call. The RunTagMacro helper from the ribbon does not cater for that.

Comment: Nice, I can call it myself! Now I can proceed with making awesome things, thanks again! :D

Answer (score 2):

```
XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcWorkbookInsert, 1);
```

returns a `bool`: `true` - success, `false` - failure

So casting it to `ExcelReference` is the cause of the `exception`.

Answer (score 0):

You may need an xlcNew before that xlcWorkbookInsert. Take a look in the Excel-Dna source at the GetApplication method in Excel.cs.